# Cannot instantiate abstract class ProductAbstract in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting error in laravel controller when use abstract

code sample

```
use App\Product; (=> abstract class Product{})

class ProductController extends Controller
{

new Product();  // here error
}
.....


error at new Product();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an object(new Product();) directly from an abstract class in your controller  because abstract classes are to act like templates for other classes that should follow structure, if you need then  create and use then create a new class for the abstract class to  make an object you can use, as below .

for eg:

change your  `abstract class Product{}` to as below

```
abstract class AbstractProduct
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }
}
```

then Create a separate Class that extends AbstractProduct

```
class Product extends AbstractProduct
{
    public function requiredFunction()
    {
        
    }
}
```

then use your approach; do use as per your requirement

```
use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller {

    new Product(); 
}
```